# Trouble with package functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

Sorry if ma question isn't appropriate but I just get a new job and I'm reinstalling all the necessary packages on my new computer right now and I have troubl with the functions packages.

I put pip install functions in the terminal, it worked but onc I lauch the script, here's the error I got :

```
  File "stockprice.py", line 13, in <module>
    import functions
  File "C:\Users\evanalonso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\functions.py", line 68
    nodes = tuple(map(lambda (k, v): process_node(inner, k, v),
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't understand, on my personal computer I didn't have this error ever so I'm quite confused.

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't put parentheses around the arguments to lambda.  `lambda k, v: ...`

Comment: If you don't control that code, try reinstalling a different version of it. They appear to introduced an error in the version you're using.